# Validation of IPV4 and IPV6 addresses in Struts 1.2

Tags: ipv6, struts-1, ipv4, struts-validation

I'm struggling to find a solution for below.
Validation of IPV4 and IPV6 address using the struts taglibs framework(Struts 1.2).

Any suggestions please,i have searched the net too but i do not want a solution in terms of regular expression.Please help with this

The Struts Version which im using is Struts 1.2
I also want to show a alert message when the IPV4 and IPV6 address validation takes place.

Please provide me with the code snippet for the same since im struggling for a long time

Comment: Can anyone please post the Java solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it in Java code inside a scriptlet inside the JSP, if indeed you're bound to working inside a JSP.  And inside the Java code, you can leverage existing regular expressions to validate IP addresses.

Comment: Can anyone please post the Java solution